# Panelizer settings page not found for OG group node

Tags: organic-groups, entities, chaos-tool-suite, panels

I have a site with several content types, all of which are OG content except one type, Group, which is a group.

I also have [Panelizer](https://drupal.org/project/panelizer) and [Panels Everywhere](https://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere) enabled. When I go to edit the default Panelizer settings for each content type, I have no problem doing so, *except* when the node type is Group. I can turn on Panelizer for Groups but then when I go to set the default settings for individual view modes, I get a "page not found" error.

[image]

I've cleared caches, rebuilt the registry, and even reinstalled Drupal, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is correct, though not very user-friendly, behavior. The user must enable a default panel, or trying to set settings for the default panel will not work.

on admin/types/manage/[nodetype]:

[image]